# @Autowired null pointer exception in Jboss RestEasy Application

Tags: java, spring, jboss, resteasy, wildfly-8

I'm changing my application from Jersey to RestEasy application. It's working fone with Jersey configurations in Web.xml when deployed in Wildfly 8.2.

But after changing the configurations from Jersey to RestEasy, it's still deployed but I get null pointer exception when trying to access `@Autowired` object's particualr method. To be more clear, the `Autowired` does not create a object at startup which results in this error. I was trying to clear this error for more than a day. Any help would be appreciated

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Web Application</display-name>
    <distributable />
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.promarvel.filter.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myPackage" />

    <!-- Add new DAOs here -->

    <!-- Add new Managers here -->
</beans>
```

I get error if I try to access a Autowired object at any time. For example, here's my SessionFilter which tries to access UserService.java

```
package com.myPackage.filter;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.myPackage.model.SessionDetails;
import com.myPackage.service.UserService;
import com.myPackage.util.DateUtil;

@Component
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {

        try {

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            String url = request.getRequestURI();
            String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");

            SessionDetails sessionDetails = new SessionDetails();
            sessionDetails.setBrowserDetails(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
            sessionDetails.setIpAddress("192.168.1.1");
            sessionDetails.setLoginTime(new Date());
            sessionDetails.setLoginUserName("UNKNOWN USER");
            sessionDetails.setActive(false);
            sessionDetails.setLoginStatus("INVALID SESSIONID");
            sessionDetails.setLastReplicationTime(new Date());

            //System.out.println(userService);   => Null Pointer Exception
            userService.saveLoginUserDetails(sessionDetails);    => Null Pointer Exception
            chain.doFilter(req, response);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to do every solution suggested in many posts, even I've added an empty beans.xml file, it still didn't work.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

// Uses JDK 8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

// 1. Get dependencies from Maven local repository
// 2. Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}

task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/myPackage"
    with war
}

configurations {
    provided
}
  sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}

//Project dependencies
dependencies {
    //JUnit testing framework
    compile 'junit:junit:4.4'

    //Spring framework core
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.4.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.0.0.RELEASE'

    //jersyclient for REST API
    //compile 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:1.18.3'
    //compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.3'

    //MySQL database driver
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'

    //Hibernate framework 
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.2.2'

    //Servlet API
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    //Base-64 Apache commons
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'

    //log4j
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.10'

    //XmlBeans Equity Valuation
    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'

    //Poi Equity Valuation
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1'

    //Poi ooxml Equity Valuation
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.10.1'

    //Poi ooxml Schemas Equity Valuation
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.10.1'

    //Jacob Equity Valuation
    compile 'jacob:jacob:1.18-M2'

    //Google gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    //compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.18.3'

    provided 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.11.Final'

    war.dependsOn explodedWar

}
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try putting `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your application.xml and also modify `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myPackage" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myPackage.*" />`

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer with @Autowire results majorly because of 2 reasons:

1. Either the class is not marked as a Spring Component.
2. Application context is not able to aware about bean.

So, make sure your UserService class is annotated with @Component or with child annotations @Controller, @Service, @Repository, based on your use case. And also you are scanning the package in your applicationContext.xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.with.UserService"></context:component-scan>
```